# Out of several options, how to execute one of them at random in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

How to pick one execution flow at random, out of several alternatives, in a trainable fashion? For example:

```
import random
from tensorflow import keras

class RandomModel(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, model_set):
        super(RandomModel, self).__init__()
        self.models = model_set


    def call(self, inputs):
        """Calls one of its models at random"""
        return random.sample(self.models, 1)[0](inputs)


def new_model():
    return keras.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
    ])

model = RandomModel({new_model(), new_model()})
model.build(input_shape=(32, 784))
model.summary()
```

While this code [runs](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lY-4mW_utY1dzaVnjVsax8PQKz3YDQqN), it doesn't seem to allow gradients to backpropagate. This is its output:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Perhaps the simplest fix to the code above would be to have a TensorFlow version of `random.sample(self.models, 1)[0](inputs)`.

Answer (score 0):

I found [a way](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lY-4mW_utY1dzaVnjVsax8PQKz3YDQqN) to do this. However, execution is slow, because of nested `tf.cond` operations:

```
def random_network_applied_to_inputs(inputs, networks):
    """
    Returns a tf.cond tree that does binary search
    before applying a network to the inputs.
    """
    length = len(networks)

    index = tf.random.uniform(
        shape=[],
        minval=0,
        maxval=length,
        dtype=tf.dtypes.int32
    )

    def branch(lower_bound, upper_bound):
        if lower_bound + 1 == upper_bound:
            return networks[lower_bound](inputs)
        else:
            center = (lower_bound + upper_bound) // 2
            return tf.cond(
                pred=index < center,
                true_fn=lambda: branch(lower_bound, center),
                false_fn=lambda: branch(center, upper_bound)
            )

    return branch(0, length)
```

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure if, due to the strange semantics of `tf.cond`, only one network get executed.